# Three Opera Rendering Issues

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, opera

There are probably duplicate questions.

First, count overflow in the question list.

[Count overflow in the question list](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/7415/stackoverflowanswersand.png)

Second, the login button gets cut off.

[Login Button Cutoff](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/7796/stackoverflowlogincutof.png)

Third, at the bottom of the "Ask question" page the tags are cutoff.

[Tags cutoff on ask question page](http://img166.imageshack.us/img166/3718/superusertagsbottoncuto.png)

Comment: Sadly, all 3 of these are duplicates. brb.

Comment: tag button dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6132/superuser-bug-badge-border-is-cut-off-in-chrome-fine-in-firefox/6160#6160

Comment: The first two are font issues, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/bug-login-page-layout-broken-ubuntu-ff-3 . Originally there was an image showing the same error.

Comment: Yet another tag duplicate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/tag-borders-in-opera

Comment: Ian's "duplicate" is not in fact a duplicate. See my answer below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It also looks like you're artificially extending browser font size beyond +1.. we don't support that.

We only support -1 and +1 -- and true page level zoom in all modern/recent browsers works perfectly to any zoom level, of course.

See here: **The Two Types of Browser Zoom**

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001212.html

Comment: Jeff, as far as I can tell I am not using font zoom. I am using Opera 9.64 on Windows XP SP3. I will however, collect a larger dataset than opera on my laptop.

Comment: then I bet you have DPI adjusted in the OS, which is effectively the same thing. I'd try a few different browsers, first.

Comment: Seeing the same, edge cut off only on Opera at 100% but the other browsers (IE, FF and Chrome) keep the border edge.

Comment: that's a bug in opera/chrome, not us. works in Firefox..

Comment: Chrome keeps the button edges fine. Just Opera then.